# Image of the set under $f(z)=\frac{z-i}{z-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

In my course in complex analisys i was given following problem:

> Find the image of set $D$ under the map $f$ if $D=\{z \in \mathbb C| 0 < Re(z) < 1\}$ and $f=\frac{z-i}{z-1}$.

The problem is that I don't quite understand how to describe the image. I am supposed to use some geometric properties of Möbius transformations like preservation of angles, but I can't see how.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The image should be something easily described, such as a half-plane or disk.  You may want to use the fact that Möbius transformations send circles to circles, and preserve orientation.  It might also be helpful to remember that lines are circles through the point at infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $D$ is an open strip of the complex plane whose left and right boundaries are described, respectively, by $\{z=z_r+iz_i\in\mathbb{C}:z=iz_i\}$ and $\{z=z_r+iz_i\in\mathbb{C}:z=1+iz_i\}$. You should look at the image of those lines under $f$ and then fill in in between since Möbius transformations take lines and circles to lines and circles and fill in everything in between by continuity.

Comment: So in general if I have some subset of $\mathbb C$ with two boundaries (or more) I should find Images of them and use your last fact about Möbius transformations?

Comment: Yeah, Möbius transformations will map boundaries to boundaries. Then, by continuity, the interior will be mapped to the interior. In general you can find the image of one interior point of your domain to figure out what the interior of the image is.

Comment: "take curves to curves" doesn't help - the point is that they take lines and circles to lines and circles.

Comment: You are correct, I've amended the answer.